# Pretreatment for galvanizing primer

Tags: corrosion, manufacturing-engineering

I currently need to paint a steel structure with galvanizing primer.  The primer is an epoxy with >90% Zinc content.  The TDS for the primer states that intimate contact with the substrate is needed to achieve full effect.

This makes sense to me...

However, the paint spec and certification for the paint mandates an iron phosphate coating as pretreatment for the primer.  Does this not prevent intimate contact?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: The data sheet should also mention the cleaning method or process to be used. At the very least a reference to the SSPC (Society for Protective Coatings) level of cleaning.

Comment: TDS recommends removal of contaminants and near white shot blast... no mention of chemical pretreatment.  SSPC-SP10.  UL certification requires this + phosphatizing.

Comment: It makes sense if it requires SP10 that there probably wouldn't be an additional chemical treatment - that's about as clean as steel can get. I'm not sure how the iron phosphate will impact the bonding of the primer.

Comment: The phosphatizing agent is usually used on non-blasted material to etch the substrate by creating a rough crystalline iron phosphate layer on the surface.  My question is: won't this crystalline layer inhibit the effectiveness of the zinc?

Comment: Are you using a primer and paint from different manufacturers? That is likely a warranty no-no. Also, if your question is about whether the paint manufacturer will warranty the final product, *they* are the only people whose answer matters.

Comment: No, I am using the customer's UL certified process for the primer, but after prototyping we will need to get our own process UL certified. This is the motivation for my question. If not phosphatizing is superior corrosion protection then it is also a cost savings.